# Trying to fetch and replace the last value (character or word) in an input box by matching or comparing it with another value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out how I can fetch the last value (word or character) in an input box store it in a variable then replace the last value from a set of values if it has an exact or partial match.

The items inside the `bindname-block` consist of values. Let's say for example I type in the text:

> Web Development `anna`
>
> Web Development `an`

The last value `anna` or `an` should be replaced within the input box once I have clicked on the set of list of values that has a corresponding or partial match which is `@annaenriquez` or any values that have the following text `anna` or `an` so basically you are not limited to only one choice

The code below is a work in progress that I have been trying to solve.

```js
    $('#raintool-app').on('click', '.-bindname-inactive', function() {
    
        let name = $(this).text();
        $('.task-label input').select().val(function(i, value) { 
            return value + " " + name;
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('-bindname-inactive -bindname-active');

    });

    $('#raintool-app').on('change', '.select-block', function() {
        // var value = $(this).val();
        let name = $(this).val();
        $('.task-label input').select().val(function(i, value) { 
            return value + " " + name;
        });

        // console.log(value);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="#raintool-app">


<div class="task-label">
    <input type="text" />
</div>

<ul class="bindname-block">
                <li data-name="annaenriquez" class="bindname-pill -name-annaenriquez -bindname-active -display-name">@annaenriquez</li>
            
                <li data-name="conchui" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-conchui">@conchui</li>
            
                <li data-name="donelleagudo" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-donelleagudo -display-name">@donelleagudo</li>
            
                <li data-name="dwezilmanuel" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-dwezilmanuel -display-name">@dwezilmanuel</li>
            
                <li data-name="ellaborlongan" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-ellaborlongan -display-name">@ellaborlongan</li>
            
                <li data-name="gabmamites" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-gabmamites -display-name">@gabmamites</li>
            
                <li data-name="janelleyu" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-janelleyu -display-name">@janelleyu</li>
            
                <li data-name="jasanmiguel" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-jasanmiguel -display-name">@jasanmiguel</li>
            
                <li data-name="jpdguzman" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-jpdguzman -display-name">@jpdguzman</li>
            
                <li data-name="juliusmiguel" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-juliusmiguel">@juliusmiguel</li>
            
                <li data-name="kimtan" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-kimtan -display-name">@kimtan</li>
            
                <li data-name="lorenzcapellan" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-lorenzcapellan -display-name">@lorenzcapellan</li>
            
                <li data-name="migobundoc" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-migobundoc">@migobundoc</li>
            
                <li data-name="noeldelacruz" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-noeldelacruz -display-name">@noeldelacruz</li>
            
                <li data-name="rozhelturgo" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-rozhelturgo">@rozhelturgo</li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to implement a name mention That would need some more sophisticated logic. But for this use case I am popping the last word and replacing with clicked item

```js
$('#raintool-app').on('click', '.-bindname-inactive', function() {

  let name = $(this).text();
  $('.task-label input').select().val(function(i, value) {
    var keywords = value.split(' ');
    
    var mention = keywords.pop();
    
    return  mention.startsWith('@') ? keywords.join(' ') + " " + name : value;
  });
  $(this).toggleClass('-bindname-inactive -bindname-active');

});

$('#raintool-app').on('change', '.select-block', function() {
  // var value = $(this).val();
  let name = $(this).val();
  $('.task-label input').select().val(function(i, value) {
    return value + " " + name;
  });

  // console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="raintool-app">


  <div class="task-label">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>

  <ul class="bindname-block">
    <li data-name="annaenriquez" class="bindname-pill -name-annaenriquez -bindname-active -display-name">@annaenriquez</li>

    <li data-name="conchui" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-conchui">@conchui</li>

    <li data-name="donelleagudo" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-donelleagudo -display-name">@donelleagudo</li>

    <li data-name="dwezilmanuel" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-dwezilmanuel -display-name">@dwezilmanuel</li>

    <li data-name="ellaborlongan" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-ellaborlongan -display-name">@ellaborlongan</li>

    <li data-name="gabmamites" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-gabmamites -display-name">@gabmamites</li>

    <li data-name="janelleyu" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-janelleyu -display-name">@janelleyu</li>

    <li data-name="jasanmiguel" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-jasanmiguel -display-name">@jasanmiguel</li>

    <li data-name="jpdguzman" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-jpdguzman -display-name">@jpdguzman</li>

    <li data-name="juliusmiguel" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-juliusmiguel">@juliusmiguel</li>

    <li data-name="kimtan" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-kimtan -display-name">@kimtan</li>

    <li data-name="lorenzcapellan" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-lorenzcapellan -display-name">@lorenzcapellan</li>

    <li data-name="migobundoc" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-migobundoc">@migobundoc</li>

    <li data-name="noeldelacruz" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-noeldelacruz -display-name">@noeldelacruz</li>

    <li data-name="rozhelturgo" class="bindname-pill -bindname-inactive -name-rozhelturgo">@rozhelturgo</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to check if the last value has `@` character so that if it has it will join or append without replacing the last value that has an `@` character also.

Comment: added a new answer. if last word starts with @ then do logic you want to have another check if mention is initial few letters of name